# from openpyxl.chart.title import Title - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: javascript, python, django, excel, openpyxl

**Question**
No changes to this module that I am aware of.  Another separate custom program was installed on the same computer then the errors below started.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

**Errors 3**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "log.py", line 100, in error_catcher response = func()

File "models.py", line 852, in func instance.main()

File "models.py", line 1061, in main data_obj = report.Main(*self.args)

File "report.py", line 95, in **init** self.data_manager()

File "report.py", line 113, in data_manager self.equivdod_report('DoD Equiv')

File "report.py", line 328, in equivdod_report datas)

File "scriptexcel.py", line 230, in equivdod_report ytitle=r'Design Usage (%)'

File "excelcreator.py", line 376, in hist__init__ self.title_params(bc.title)

File "excelcreator.py", line 767, in title_params baseline=1000

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rPr'

**excelcreator.py (Segments from this module)**

```js
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.chart.title import Title
import openpyxl.drawing.text as oxldt
import os
import re
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import datetime


class Excel():

 def hist__init__(self,
      sheet_name,
      mincol=None,
      maxcol=None,
       minrow=None,
       maxrow=None,
       bc=None,
       title=None,
      ytitle=None,
      xtitle=None):

  if bc is None:
   bc = BarChart()
   bc.title = title
   bc.y_axis.title = ytitle
   bc.legend.position = 't'
   self.title_params(bc.title)
   self.title_params(bc.y_axis.title)
  xval = Reference(
   self.wb[sheet_name],
   min_col=mincol-1,
   min_row=2,
   max_row=maxrow)
  data = Reference(
   self.wb[sheet_name],
   min_col=mincol,
   max_col=maxcol,
   min_row=minrow,
   max_row=maxrow)

  return bc, xval, data


 def title_params(self, title):
  if title is not None:
   title.tx.rich.p[0].r.rPr = CharacterProperties(
    latin=oxldt.Font(typeface='Arial'),
    baseline=1000
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

`p[0].r` is a list. You might want to try `p[0].r[0].rPr`

Look at the source code for chart titles or the OOXML specification schema for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As per answer from Charlie Clark this resolved the issue:

p[0].r changed to p[0].r[0].rPr